# How to retrieve the right commit hash?

Tags: git, hashcode, cherry-pick

I had a `master` with a few commits, I moved back to the first commit, created a branch from there and used `cherry-pick` to apply one of the commits from the `master` branch. But due to some conflicts I got a message like:

```
Automatic cherry-pick failed.  After resolving the conflicts,
mark the corrected paths with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
and commit the result with: 

    git commit -c some_hash_id
```

The problem is, resolving the conflicts took me a while and in the meantime I closed the terminal with the message and now I don't know what commit hash I should use when committing the resolved files. How do I find it out?

*If I didn't provide enough details, please ask for them in the comments.*

Edit:

```
$ git status
# On branch upgrade
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file1.php
#   new file:   file2.php
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      file3.php
#   both modified:      file4.php
#   both modified:      file5.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   [long list of files...]
```

`file3.php`, `file4.php` and `file5.php` are the ones I had to resolve conflicts in.

```
$ git cherry-pick --continue
error: unknown option `continue'
usage: git cherry-pick [options] <commit-ish>

    -n, --no-commit       don't automatically commit
    -e, --edit            edit the commit message
    -x                    append commit name when cherry-picking
    -r                    no-op (backward compatibility)
    -s, --signoff         add Signed-off-by:
    -m, --mainline <n>    parent number
    --rerere-autoupdate   update the index with reused conflict resolution if possible
    --ff                  allow fast-forward

$ git cherry-pick --abort
error: unknown option `abort'
usage: git cherry-pick [options] <commit-ish>

    -n, --no-commit       don't automatically commit
    -e, --edit            edit the commit message
    -x                    append commit name when cherry-picking
    -r                    no-op (backward compatibility)
    -s, --signoff         add Signed-off-by:
    -m, --mainline <n>    parent number
    --rerere-autoupdate   update the index with reused conflict resolution if possible
    --ff                  allow fast-forward
```

But the docs say:

```
--continue

    Continue the operation in progress using the information in .git/sequencer. Can be used to continue after resolving conflicts in a failed cherry-pick or revert.
```

And I don't have such file (I checked) so maybe I can't use these commands now.

I'm using git version 1.7.1.

Comment: What does `git status` say? AFAIK git stores cherry-pick and other information in the .git folder so it shouldn't matter if you close the terminal in between. Chances are git thinkgs you're still in the middle of the cherry-pick so you can just do your thing, add your files and `git cherry-pick --continue`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Can I mess things up by using the command you specified or will it just show an error (and do nothing) if that's not the right command to use now?

Comment: You can always `git cherry-pick --abort` to abort (if it's even still in progress) and redo the cherry-pick

Comment: @TimCastelijns My git doesn't seem to know either `--continue` or `--abort` parameters.

Comment: Does it say `error: no cherry-pick or revert in progress` ?

Comment: That is quite strange. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick. They should be available, what version git are you running? (`git --version`)

Comment: @TimCastelijns See last update to my question. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019, 4 years later) should do a better job keeping the status of a cherry-pick or revert which resolving conflicts.

See [commit 4a72486](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a72486de97b5c6b0979b2b51e50c268bdb0d4f6), [commit b07d9bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b07d9bfd171d881a02d110b68673c58cb63e9f62) (16 Apr 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b51a0fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b51a0fdc3822c2ef260f6d496b6df6d33b101e8a), 13 May 2019)</sup>

> ### fix `cherry-pick`/`revert` status after commit

> If the user commits a conflict resolution using `git commit` in the middle of a sequence of cherry-picks/reverts then `git status` missed the fact that a cherry-pick/revert is still in progress.

And:

> ### `commit`/`reset`: try to clean up sequencer state

> When cherry-picking or reverting a sequence of commits and if the final pick/revert has conflicts and the user uses `git commit` to commit the conflict resolution and does not run `git cherry-pick --continue` then the sequencer state is left behind.
>
> This can cause problems later.
>
> In my case I cherry-picked a sequence of commits the last one of which I committed with `git commit` after resolving some conflicts, then a while later, on a different branch I aborted a revert which rewound my HEAD to the end of the cherry-pick sequence on the previous branch.
>
> Avoid this potential problem by removing the sequencer state if we're committing or resetting the final pick in a sequence.

---

With Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), the code to read state files used by the sequencer machinery for "`git status`" has been made more robust against a corrupt or stale
state files.

See [commit ed5b1ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed5b1ca10b2644f1af3bdfa3da32c67f4df1aa46), [commit 3e81bcc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e81bccdf3ceab531e95ba3846083dbc8ba0e319), [commit d258dc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d258dc16c1bf92c01135c38130869da7808ed739) (27 Jun 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd48ccf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd48ccf4a4daca79a1e828dec7bee91c4aebc81e), 19 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### status: do not report errors in sequencer/todo

> [commit 4a72486](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a72486de97b5c6b0979b2b51e50c268bdb0d4f6) ("fix cherry-pick/revert status after commit",
> 2019-04-16, Git v2.22.0-rc0) used `parse_insn_line()` to parse the first line of the `todo` list to check if it was a pick or revert.
>
> However, if the `todo` list is left over from an old cherry-pick or revert and references a commit that no longer exists then `parse_insn_line()` prints an error message [which is confusing for users](https://public-inbox.org/git/3bc58c33-4268-4e7c-bf1a-fe349b3cb037@www.fastmail.com/).
>
> Instead parse just the command name so that the user is alerted to the presence of stale sequencer state by status reporting that a cherry-pick or revert is in progress.
>
> Note that we should not be leaving stale sequencer state lying around (or at least not as often) after commit [b07d9bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b07d9bfd171d881a02d110b68673c58cb63e9f62) ("commit/reset: try to clean up sequencer state", 2019-04-16, Git v2.22.0-rc0).
> However, the user may still have stale state that predates that commit.
>
> Also avoid printing an error message if for some reason the user has a file called `sequencer` in `$GIT_DIR`.

---

During a cherry-pick or revert session that works on multiple commits, "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/391414e971d552e5e0fa1363347ec2c076062daf/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> did not give correct information, which has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit a096a88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb) (27 Jun 2023) by [Jacob Keller (`jacob-keller`)](https://github.com/jacob-keller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 391414e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/391414e971d552e5e0fa1363347ec2c076062daf), 06 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`a096a889f4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb):fix cherry-pick/revert status when doing multiple commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jacob Keller</sup>

> The status report for an in-progress cherry-pick does not show the current commit if the cherry-pick happens as part of a series of multiple commits: $ [`git cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))</sup>   < one of the cherry-picks fails to merge clean > Cherry-pick currently in progress.
> (run "`git cherry-pick`" `--continue` to continue) (use "[`git cherry-pick --skip`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/sequencer.txt#L6)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---skip))</sup> to skip this patch) (use "[`git cherry-pick --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/sequencer.txt#L15)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---abort))</sup> to cancel the cherry-pick operation) $ [`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/git-status.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> On branch `<branch>` Your branch is ahead of '' by 1 commit.
> (use "[`git push to`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/git-push.txt#L501)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-to))</sup> publish your local commits) Cherry-pick currently in progress.
> (run "`git cherry-pick`" `--continue` to continue) (use "`git cherry-pick --skip`" to skip this patch) (use "`git cherry-pick --abort`" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)
>
> The `show_cherry_pick_in_progress()` function prints "Cherry-pick currently in progress".
> That function does have a more verbose print based on whether the `cherry_pick_head_oid` is null or not.
> If it is not null, then a more helpful message including which commit is actually being picked is displayed.
>
> The introduction of the "Cherry-pick currently in progress" message comes from [4a72486](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a72486de97b5c6b0979b2b51e50c268bdb0d4f6) ("fix cherry-pick/revert status after commit", 2019-04-17, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b51a0fdc3822c2ef260f6d496b6df6d33b101e8a)).
> This commit modified `wt_status_get_state()` in order to detect that a cherry-pick was in progress even if the user has used [`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a096a889f43a40223bae89efa7d1896e0d4c37cb/Documentation/git-commit.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> in the middle of the sequence.
>
> The check used to detect this is the call to `sequencer_get_last_command`.
> If the sequencer indicates that the lass command was a `REPLAY_PICK,` then the `state->cherry_pick_in_progress` is set to 1 and the `cherry_pick_head_oid` is initialized to the `null_oid`.
> Similar behavior is done for the case of `REPLAY_REVERT`.
>
> It happens that this call of `sequencer_get_last_command` will always report the action even if the user hasn't interrupted anything.
> Thus, during a range of cherry-picks or reverts, the `cherry_pick_head_oid` and `revert_head_oid` will always be overwritten and initialized to the null oid.
>
> This results in status always displaying the terse message which does not include commit information.
>
> Fix this by adding an additional check so that we do not re-initialize the `cherry_pick_head_oid` or `revert_head_oid` if we have already set the `cherry_pick_in_progress` or `revert_in_progress` bits.
> This ensures that `git status` will display the more helpful information when its available.